# Update facebook status via SMS

Tags: php, facebook, sms

Hello I am developing a SMS application for updating facebook status in PHP. I can collect username and password of user. 
I know it can be done by [Status.set](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Status.set) ,but how can I use the username and password and get the necessary session key and as such. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help someone

```
function setFacebookStatus($status, $login_email, $login_pass, $debug=false) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://login.facebook.com/login.php?m&amp;next=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fhome.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=' . urlencode($login_email) . '&pass=' . urlencode($login_pass) . '&login=' . urlencode("Log in"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.12) Gecko/2009070611 Firefox/3.0.12");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://m.facebook.com/home.php');
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
preg_match("/input type=\"hidden\" name=\"post_form_id\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $form_id);
preg_match("/input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fb_dtsg\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $fb_dtsg);
preg_match("/input type=\"hidden\" name=\"charset_test\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $charset_test);
preg_match("/input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" name=\"update\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $update);
preg_match_all("#<form([^>]*)>(.*)</form>#Ui", $page, $form_ar);
for($i=0;$i<count($form_ar[0]);$i++) {
if(stristr($form_ar[0][$i],"post_form_id")) preg_match("/form action=\"(.*?)\"/", $page, $form_num);    
}
$strpost = 'post_form_id=' . $form_id[1] . '&status=' . urlencode($status) . '&update=' . urlencode($update[1]) . '&charset_test=' . urlencode($charset_test[1]) . '&fb_dtsg=' . urlencode($fb_dtsg[1]);
if($debug) {
    echo "Parameters sent: ".$strpost."<hr>";
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strpost );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://m.facebook.com' . $form_num[1]);
curl_exec($ch);
if ($debug) {
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    echo curl_errno($ch) . '-' . curl_error($ch);
    echo "<br><br>Your Facebook status seems to have been updated.";
}
curl_close($ch); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) (offline_access). The user will still have to [authenticate with oauth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), the most 'inobtrusive' way would be 
the [Desktop Application](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop) route

Comment: hey but it says "Facebook's OAuth implementation does not include explicit desktop application support. However, if your desktop application can embed a Web browser, you can add Facebook support to your application easily using the same OAuth User-Agent Flow used by JavaScript clients."